# Which parameter set has been used?

Tags: powershell, parameters, optional-parameters

I've used advanced parameter handling to support multiple parameter sets. Is there any pre-defined variable or way to determine which parameter set has been used to call the script?

e.g. something like

```
if($parameterSet -eq "set1") { ... } elseif ($parameterSet -eq "set2") { ... }
```

?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Check the $PSCmdlet variable:

```
$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
```

Answer (score 30):

You can check in your script:

```
$PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName
```